# "The group doesn't contain any members."

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

Get this error while assigning the work order to a resource type - "group"
[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLILe.png)

I have currently created a group "CRM Team" and have tried to assign a work order to that group. However, when I try to schedule that work order, I am getting the "The group doesn't contain any members" error.

Does anyone know how to add members when resource type is " Group" in field service?

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: Is this question programming related?

Comment: No. It's kind of a functional question. We need a way to associate a group resource with the work order.

Comment: SO is for asking questions about programming. Business software usage is off topic here and should be asked on SuperUser.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that this is off topic and will soon be deleted. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic